# Could d3.dsv method change by itself downloadable content charset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, character-encoding, fetch

I need to feed d3.dsv method with the text file exported from Excel. As to local settings all Excels here would make files with Windows-1251 charset by default.

Is my guess correct that even if I put the right charset value in "init" parameter of d3.dsv method I will not see correctly imported Cyrillic text in console? Unless I use some special recode function for the text received? I used all combinations for charset settings in meta of a html header and in "init" but hasn't succeeded. Is the "init" parameter (which is based on the fetch JS method) useless in this case?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var doc = "raw/test.txt";
            var init = {headers: {"Content-type": "text/plain; charset=Windows-1251"}};

            d3.dsv("\t", doc, init, ).then(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            });


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if d3.dsv will accept character encoding. [D3 dsv docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#dsv)

Comment: @pmkro, I'v got the same idea. But why I cannot urge the browser to look at text string as at the Windows-1251 text flow? Or I cannot change this in the console tab also and only on the html page text will look fine?